# Taking advantage of alphabetical order in String database search in Java

Tags: java, search, brute-force, alphabetical

I am writing a Java program.

I have some thousands of lists stored as .txt files. Each list contains some thousands of words, which are set in alphabetical order. All words in each list are different (there are no repetitions).

I have to search these lists, in order to see whether a query-word is present in each list or not. How can I take advantage of the alphabetical order to make my search quicker? The brute-force approach (`.equals()` method) works well but takes several hours.

Thank you very much in advance for your help! I would be very grateful to you if you could also send me some bits of code.

Comment: Can you post an example of these words? And what you exactly want to search?

Comment: Add each word to a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

Comment: Thousands of files containing thousands of words should easily be searchable in a few seconds with `grep`. I wouldn't expect Java to really be much slower. Can you post your searching code?

Comment: @developer033 http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: You can read millions of lines a second with `BufferedReader`. How are you reading these files?

Answer (score 1):

Java provides `Arrays.binarySearch(Object[] array, Object key)` and `Collections.binarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list, T key)` methods which will improve your results. They're the not optimal solution, but they're easy to use and much better than brute force.